# How do I set a button in viewcell in xamarin.forms to call a command from the content page viewmodel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

In the GroceryListViewModel is a command called ButtonClicked that I would like a button to use. However, that button is located in the ViewCell of a ListView and can't access the command. What I'm currently doing causes the command to be called every time the ViewCell loads and whenever the ViewCell is clicked on. The button in question doesn't work for a few of the ViewCells at the top of the list but works further down the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:FoodLifeApp.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="FoodLifeApp.PageViews.GroceryListPage"
             x:Name="GroceryList">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext >
        <VM:GroceryListViewModel x:Name="VMGroceryList"/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayList}"
            IsGroupingEnabled="True"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
        <ListView.Header >
            <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" 
                       Text="{Binding SearchText}" 
                       HeightRequest="40" 
                       SearchCommand="{Binding Search}"
                       />
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="20">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Heading}"  
                           BackgroundColor="LightGray" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="40">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ProductSize}" 
                               FontSize="10" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Button ImageSource="{Binding ButtonImage}" 
                                     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding ProductName}" 
                                     Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClicked, Source={x:Reference VMGroceryList}}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
class GroceryListViewModel : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<ShoppingList> _ListOfShoppingList;
        private List<ShoppingList> _SearchResults;
        private String _searchText;
        private Command searchCommand;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public GroceryListViewModel()
        {
            var meatList = new ShoppingList()
            {
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Beef", ProductQuantity=7},
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Chicken", ProductQuantity=3},
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Pork", ProductQuantity=5},
            };
            meatList.Heading = "Meats";
            var fruitList = new ShoppingList()
            {
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Apples", ProductQuantity=12},
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Bananas", ProductQuantity=6},
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Peaches", ProductQuantity=4},
            };
            fruitList.Heading = "Fruits";
            var vegetableList = new ShoppingList()
            {
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Corn", ProductQuantity=8},
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Potatoes", ProductQuantity=9},
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Green Beans", ProductQuantity=8},
                new ShoppingItem() { ProductName="Broccoli", ProductQuantity=1}
            };
            vegetableList.Heading = "Vegetables";
            DisplayList = new List<ShoppingList>()
            {
                meatList,
                fruitList,
                vegetableList
            };
            Search = new Command(async () =>
            {
                ShoppingList tempList = new ShoppingList();
                tempList.Heading = "Search Results";
                RestHelper restH = new RestHelper();
                JObject sRes = await restH.GetKroger(SearchText);
                foreach (var currItem in sRes["data"])
                {
                    tempList.Add(new ShoppingItem() { ProductName = currItem["description"].ToString(), ProductQuantity = 0, ProductSize = currItem["items"][0]["size"].ToString()});
                }
                DisplayList = new List<ShoppingList>() { tempList };
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayList"));

            });
        }

        public List<ShoppingList> DisplayList
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsSearchingBool.IsSearchingInstance.getIsSearching())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("RETURNING SEARCH RESULTS");
                    return _SearchResults;
                } else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("RETURNING GROCERY LIST");
                    return _ListOfShoppingList;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (IsSearchingBool.IsSearchingInstance.getIsSearching())
                {
                    _SearchResults = value;
                } else
                {
                    _ListOfShoppingList = value;
                }
                base.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public String SearchText
        {
            set
            {
                if (value.Length == 0 && IsSearchingBool.IsSearchingInstance.getIsSearching() == true)
                {
                    IsSearchingBool.IsSearchingInstance.setIsSearching(false);
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayList"));
                } else if (value.Length > 0 && IsSearchingBool.IsSearchingInstance.getIsSearching() == false)
                {
                    IsSearchingBool.IsSearchingInstance.setIsSearching(true);
                    Search.CanExecute(this);
                }
                _searchText = value;
                base.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
            get
            {
                return _searchText;
            }
        }

        public ICommand Search
        {
            get; private set; 
        }

        public ICommand ButtonClicked
        {
            get
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("in button clicked");
                if (IsSearchingBool.IsSearchingInstance.getIsSearching())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("is searching");
                    return new Command<String>((itemName) => {
                        Debug.WriteLine(itemName);
                        Debug.WriteLine(_SearchResults[0].ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine(_ListOfShoppingList[0].ToString());
                        ShoppingItem temp = _SearchResults[0].Find(x => x.ProductName.Equals(itemName));
                        _SearchResults[0].Remove(temp);
                        _ListOfShoppingList[0].Add(temp);
                        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayList"));
                    });
                } else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Not searching");
                    return new Command(() => { });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post the relevant bits of `GroceryListViewModel`

Comment: I think `ButtonClicked` is defined and bound correctly, but you are doing a bunch of stuff outside of the actual Command that is making you think otherwise.

Comment: Commands can be bound using [Relative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor). The viewmodel can set to the BindingContext.

Comment: @Jason it seems like it is bound correctly and maybe just the rest of my code is bad. Would you happen to know why the command is being called several times when loading the list or why it can be called clicking anywhere on the viewcell?

Comment: why do you think the command is called "several times" when loading?  The `ButtonClicked` get may be called several times as each Cell is created, but that does not mean that the command itself is being executed.  The Writeline and if statements in your get are NOT part of the command itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button `Command` binding looks wrong

Try

```
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ButtonClicked, Source={x:Reference MyListView}}" />
```

Comment: I've tried switching to your binding and I'm still running into the same problems. The command can be called by clicking almost anywhere on the view cell, not all of the buttons seem to actually do anything and the command gets called several times on loading the list.